# How to Space Messages in Discord Using Embeds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I tried to put embeds into my ChatGPT Discord's reply

Unfortunately due to 2000 characters being the limit of a Discord message, I have to space the messages in separate columns.

However I can't figure out how to do this in embeds, as it always ends up with an error.

The Error:

````
2023-03-13 20:36:32 ERROR    src.bot -> Error while sending message: argument of type 'Embed' is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\discord PATH\PATH DISCORD\chatGPT-discord-bot-main\src\bot.py", line 30, in send_message
    if "```" in response:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'Embed' is not iterable
````

The Code:

````
async def send_message(message, user_message):
    await message.response.defer(ephemeral=isPrivate)
    try:
        responsetitle = discord.Embed(description='> **' + user_message + '** - <@' + \
            str(message.user.id) + '>\n\n')
        response = '> **' + user_message + '** - <@' + \
            str(message.user.id) + '>\n\n'
        response = discord.Embed(description=f"{response}{await responses.handle_response(user_message)}", color= 0xFFFFFF)
        response.set_thumbnail(url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Fq7BguPagAIzMtE?format=png&name=small")
        if len(response) > 1900:
            if "```" in response:
                parts = response.split("```")
                await message.followup.send(embed = parts[0])
                code_block = parts[1].split("\n")
                formatted_code_block = ""
                for line in code_block:
                    while len(line) > 1900:
                        formatted_code_block += line[:1900] + "\n"
                        line = line[1900:]
                    formatted_code_block += line + "\n" 
                if (len(formatted_code_block) > 2000):
                    code_block_chunks = [formatted_code_block[i:i+1900]
                                         for i in range(0, len(formatted_code_block), 1900)]
                    for chunk in code_block_chunks:
                        chunkmessage = discord.Embed(description = chunk)
                        chunkmessage.set_thumbnail(url= "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Fq7BguPagAIzMtE?format=png&name=small")
                        await message.followup.send(embed="```" + chunkmessage + "```")
                else:
                    formatted_code_block == formatcodeblock
                    formatcodeblock = discord.Embed(description= formatcodeblock)
                    await message.followup.send(embed = "```" + formatcodeblock + "```")
                if len(parts) >= 3:
                    parts= discord.Embed(description= parts)
                    await message.followup.send(embed = parts[2])
            else:
                response_chunks = [response[i:i+1900]
                                   for i in range(0, len(response), 1900)]
                for chunk in response_chunks:
                    chunk= discord.Embed(description = chunk)
                    await message.followup.send(embed= chunk)
        else:
            await message.followup.send(embed=response)
    except Exception as e:
        await message.followup.send("> **Error: Something went wrong, please try again later!**")
        logger.exception(f"Error while sending message: {e}")
````

This is the part which seperates the message:

````
if len(response) > 1900:
            if "```" in response:
                parts = response.split("```")
                await message.followup.send(embed = parts[0])
                code_block = parts[1].split("\n")
                formatted_code_block = ""
                for line in code_block:
                    while len(line) > 1900:
                        formatted_code_block += line[:1900] + "\n"
                        line = line[1900:]
                    formatted_code_block += line + "\n" 
                if (len(formatted_code_block) > 2000):
                    code_block_chunks = [formatted_code_block[i:i+1900]
                                         for i in range(0, len(formatted_code_block), 1900)]
                    for chunk in code_block_chunks:
                        chunkmessage = discord.Embed(description = chunk)
                        chunkmessage.set_thumbnail(url= "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Fq7BguPagAIzMtE?format=png&name=small")
                        await message.followup.send(embed="```" + chunkmessage + "```")
                else:
                    formatted_code_block == formatcodeblock
                    formatcodeblock = discord.Embed(description= formatcodeblock)
                    await message.followup.send(embed = "```" + formatcodeblock + "```")
                if len(parts) >= 3:
                    parts= discord.Embed(description= parts)
                    await message.followup.send(embed = parts[2])
            else:
                response_chunks = [response[i:i+1900]
                                   for i in range(0, len(response), 1900)]
                for chunk in response_chunks:
                    chunk= discord.Embed(description = chunk)
                    await message.followup.send(embed= chunk)
````

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you looking for? Like the error said, Embeds aren't iterable. Maybe you could assign different parts of the embed like the description, title, etc to variables and search for `"```"` there. Also, do edit your question to format your code properly.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You reassign your response string to a discord Embed here:

````
response = '> **' + user_message + '** - <@' + \
            str(message.user.id) + '>\n\n'
response = discord.Embed(description=f"{response}{await responses.handle_response(user_message)}", color= 0xFFFFFF)
        response.set_thumbnail(url="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Fq7BguPagAIzMtE?format=png&name=small")
if len(response) > 1900:
   if "```" in response:
````

That's why the error is appearing.
I recommend changing the name of the embed, maybe to response_embed or something similar.